# When I use ObjectMapper in my code, I get the issues that "Left side of mutating operator has immutable type"

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2

How can I fix it?
I just convert my app to Swift 4.2 which used Swift 3.0.
And I use the ObjectMapper(3.4.2).

```
class Discuess<author:PostAuthor,reply_to:Reply_To>: Mappable {

     var author: PostAuthor? = nil
     var reply_to: Reply_To? = nil
      required init?(map: Map) {

}
func mapping(map: Map) {
    author <- map["author"] //Left side of mutating operator has immutable type 'author.Type'
    reply_to <- map["reply_to"] //Left side of mutating operator has immutable type 'reply_to.Type'
     }    
}
```

Comment: why you dont' remove the `<author:PostAuthor,reply_to:Reply_To>`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I got it ~ hhhhh